# Need some pointers on some regex validation

Tags: javascript, regex

Given a string, it must have the following:

1. only one number
2. only one special character in (@#$*)
3. 6 lower cased letters

The string can be in any combination of the above criteria and must be 8 in length.

Examples:

1. 2@qwerty
2. ## 1asddfg
3. qwe*yt2u
4. ## qw2wqia

Here my regex so far:

```
!/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^a-z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[@#$*])\S{8,}$/.test(string)
```

It works for the above cases but breaks on cases like below:

1. 2@2qwert
2. 2@@qwert

What am I missing?

Comment: Why don't just break it into 4 simple regular expressions and require them all to match? At least will be easier to implement and read.

Comment: Why use regex?? Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: "breaks on cases like below": should they pass or fail? Fail, I assume. There is nothing requiring 6 letters in your pattern, so why should they be rejected? Also, your first and fourth lookahead make sure that the second will *always* pass, so it's redundant.

Comment: Not sure what's missing. If you've not tried it, I recommend Expresso by Ultrapico (free to download and register)

Comment: How is it breaking btw? TBH this looks like it shouldnt even work for your other groups.

Comment: The regex looks a big complex and not too easy to understand as it is, this can be trivial to implement with plain JS - is this an option for you?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum how would it work via plain js? reason i chose regex was because i couldnt really figure how to check those conditions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Description

Your expression breaks because:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^a-z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[@#$*])\S{8,}$
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^                       ^^^^^^
```

- `[^a-z]` is a negated character class, so this will match anything which is not `a-z`. I'm not sure what the purpose of this portion of the expression was for.
- `\S` will match any non white space character. This is allows for letters, numbers, unicode characters, new line characters, any symbols... etc.
- `{8,}` will allow 8 or more of the preceiding characters. This allows a string to be an infinite length. In your post you wanted the string to be at most 8 characters.
- also as a best practice you should always escape the `#` as this can be used as a comment character in some versions of regex so the expression is ready in case the `x` option is ever used.

I would modify your expression like this:

- require the string to have 1 number
- require the string to have 1 `@#$*` symbol
- require the string to have 6 `a-z` lower case letters (be sure not to use the case insenstive option)
- require the over all length of the string to have 8 characters

`^(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[@\#$*])(?=(?:.*?[a-z]){6}).{8}$`

[Live Demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/YQpb88TYaW)

[image]

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [@\#$*]                  any character of: '@', '\#', '$', '*'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (6 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){6}                     end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .{8}                     any character except \n (8 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: Very nicely formatted answer. My regex fu is not very strong so I was hoping someone could produce one, just for curiosity. I tried your live demo but it seems to fail where you don't have 6 consecutive lowercase chars: `1as1#ddfg@`.

Comment: wow that an answer! @Mrchief your example would fail since it is already over 8 characters and also broken rules 1 and 2?!

Comment: @yaojiang: Yeah... For some reason, I was hung up on 6 lower chars part while ignoring the other conditions when I added that comment. My bad!

Answer (score 3):

> What am I missing?

The reasons your tests '2@2qwert' and '2@@qwert' are incorrectly matching your regex is because there isn't anything in it that requires a minimum of 6 lowercase letters. Based on the other answers and comments to this question, I'd say replace your `(?=.*[a-z])` clause with `(?=(.*?[a-z]){6})`.

Some other minor improvements that can be made:

- You can drop the redundant `(?=.*[^a-z])` clause since all this is saying is that the string should contain at least 1 non-letter, which is already established by the digit and special character requirement.
- Replace [0-9] with \d.
- In the 3 places where you are matching wildcards prior to a character match (.*), it is slightly faster for the RegExp engine if these are made non-greedy so that there is less backtracking done when searching through the string for a match. This is done by placing a ? after the * (.*?).

Putting this together based on your regexp:

```
/^(?=.*?\d)(?=(.*?[a-z]){6})(?=.*?[@#$*])\S{8,}$/
```

This successfully matches your first 4 strings, but not the last 2.

(My original response is below in case you want a readable validate function.)

```
function validate(str)
{
  // test for digit
  if( !/\d/.test(str) ) return false;
  // test for special character
  if( !/[@#$*]/.test(str) ) return false;
  // test for 6 lowercase letters
  var letters = str.match(/[a-z]/g);
  return letters != null && letters.length == 6;
}

var tests = [ '2@qwerty', '#1asddfg', 'qwe*yt2u', '#qw2wqia', '2@2qwert', '2@@qwert' ];
for( var i=0 ; i<tests.length ; ++i )
  document.writeln(tests[i] + ": " + validate(tests[i]) + "<br/>\n");
```

Answer (score 3):

Your breaking cases should break because they do not satisfy condition #3. Having said that, I think its probably easier to use a combination of JavaScript and Regex:

```
function isValid(input) {
  return (input && input.length === 8)             /* make sure its 8 characters */
         && /[0-9]/.test(input)                    /* make sure it contains at least one digit */
         && /[@#$*]/.test(input)                   /* make sure it contains at least one special character */
         && /([^a-z]*[a-z]){6}.*/.test(input);     /* make sure it contains at least 6 lower case chars */ 
}

console.log(isValid('2@qwerty'));    // true
console.log(isValid('#1asddfg'));    // true
console.log(isValid('qwe*yt2u'));    // true
console.log(isValid('#qw2wqia'));    // true
console.log(isValid('2@2qwert'));    // false
console.log(isValid('2@@qwert'));    // false
console.log(isValid('2@qwerty'));   // now true as it satisfies #3
```

Edit: Updated the check for minimum of 6 chars based on inputs from @Sniffer (it was interesting to learn something new, see comments!)

Comment: +1 Nice regex /([^a-z]?[a-z]){6}.*/ to test for 6 non-consecutive letters. I like your solution better than mine.

Comment: @Matt I don't think `/([^a-z]?[a-z]){6}.*/` works, try `af34ddfg` It won't match

Comment: @Matt You are correct, on the line of your observation I was able to improve my expression a bit.

Comment: `/([^a-z]?[a-z]){6}.*/` works in this case as the overall string is limited to 8 characters (6 letters, 1 number, and 1 symbol) so the string `af34ddfg` would fail because it has 2 numbers and zero symbols  which are tested at other parts of this script.

Comment: @Sniffer: Strangely, my regex works for `'qwe*yt2u'` but not for `'af34ddfg'`; both of them have 6 non-consecutive characters.

Comment: Are you asking me or know the reason because I answered this a while ago and I can't remember the details of this question.

Comment: @Sniffer: I'm just telling you because I do have a test for non-consecutive characters. It seems that mine breaks when you have 2 or more consecutive numeric chars in between.

Answer (score 2):

Well I came up with a regular expression that might do what you want but you may not like the look of it but the principle behind it is simple:

```
^(?=^.{8}$)(?=\D*[0-9])(?=[^@#$*]*[@#$*])(?=([^a-z]*[a-z]){6})\S{8}$
```

This expression first makes sure there is only 8 characters `(?=^.{8}$)`.

Now the expression checks if there is a single number `(?=\D*[0-9])` no more, then it makes sure there is one special symbol `(?=[^@#$*]*[@#$*])`.

Now the expression guarantees that there is 6 lower case characters `(?=([^a-z]*[a-z]){6})`.

So we have guaranteed there is one number, one special symbol and 6 lower case characters, the sum is 8 characters so the string should be valid.

This is not the best way to do it of course as you should probably break this operation into multiple steps but I wanted to try and do it with a single expression for the fun of it, if you found any problems please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

This regex does what you need:

```
^(?=\D*\d\D*$)(?=[^@#$*]*[@#$*][^@#$*]*$)[@#$*\da-z]{8}$
```

It uses 2 look-aheads (anchored to start) to assert exactly 1 digit and 1 special, and a simple character class for all valid chars (times 8) so the rest must be lowercase (no need to count exactly 6).

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/HzS8V4jLOa) of your test cases on rubular.

Comment: Another interesting solution! However it fails on this one: `asd1234ghy@`

Comment: @Mrchief Fails? `asd1234ghy@` shouldn't match: The question says *only one number* and *must have exactly 8 characters* - this example fails for both those reasons. I've added your example to this [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/14scpEiKOB). Let me know what you mean.

Comment: You're right. I was just focussing on the 6 lower chars part.